# OpenGl 2 over Remote Desktop Connection

Tags: windows, opengl

I have an app that uses OpenGl 2.0. When I use the app normally on my computer, it works fine. When connected using Windows Remote Desktop, the app does not work because only OpenGl 1.1 is supported over Remote Desktop.

How can I get around this?

Comment: I would simply use a remote desktop solution which supports OpenGL 2.0+ or greater.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion? I have only used the default software.

Comment: Windows 10/Server 10 Server will support OpenGL over RDP with OpenGL 4.4: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rds/archive/2014/10/07/what-s-new-in-remote-desktop-services-for-the-next-version-of-windows-server.aspx

Comment: @horns - I suggest you do a little research on the subject.  There are literally dozens of options besides the default built-in client.